# Jeditable enabled only on user profile page when logged in

Tags: php, javascript, jeditable

I know how to display code using an `IF` statement in `PHP` checking for `$_SESSION` variables of the user currently logged in, but I am not sure how to enforce this check when javascript is involved.

More specifically, I want to follow the Jeditable tutorial from http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable and make it so that fields are only editable to a logged in user when viewing his own profile. Viewing other profiles will only display content regularly.

Seems fairly simple, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So you should embed jeditable.js only when user logged-in and only on his own page.